# Making a "Pressed" effect on a Panel using Angular bootstrap Version 0.13.4

Tags: css, angular-bootstrap

I plan to have a grid of 6 rectangle panels, (3 X 2). Each panel will act as a button that will open a different module within my system. I am looking for some effect on mouseover or hover to apply to each panel so that the user can tell that the panel is being interacted with before they actually click the panel. (It will show them that it is clickable and not just read only data). For example, something that will give the panel a "pressed" effect before the panel actually being clicked would be nice. (I am open to other suggestions).

I am currently using angular bootstrap version 0.13.4.

Here is the code for the panel that I will be applying it to:

```
<div
        data-ng-if="vb.isAuthorized('ROLE_STAFF','ROLE_SRPROFESSOR')">
        <div class="panel panel-default panelAttributes panel-snap"
            data-ng-click="vb.change('classmodule')">
            <div class="panel-body" id="content">
                <div class="row col-md-12">
                    <img src="/WebContent/img/Shape@3x.png" alt=""
                        class="img-responsive resize" /> <br> <span
                        class="classText Placement">Class Module</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="numericalText divContent">5</p>
                    <p class="infoText divContent">Community Colleges</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="numericalText divContent">28</p>
                    <p class="infoText divContent">Counties <br>Served</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please let me know of any good suggestions! I am not sure what design conventions expect with things like this, so I wanted to see what ideas anyone here might have.

I am currently using a shadow effect:

```
.panel-snap {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF5A00, #FFAE00);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF5A00 0%, #FFAE00 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF5A00 0%, #FFAE00 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF5A00 0%, #FFAE00 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FF5A00 0%, #FFAE00 100%);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #A9A9A9;
}
```

Feel free to let me know of any questions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is purely your choice, of course there are some patterns you can follow. Google Material is very popular (for good reason) perhaps you can get some inspiration from [here](https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html) as a starting point. Another good resource for quick inspiration at [CodeDrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/?s=button&search-type=posts).

I often like to use `SASS` or `LESS` to lighten/darken by 10% for hover events. This way you can set a master color and manipulate it in precise and consistent ways. You could even use a mixin.

Personally, I think less is more when it comes to interactivity, but it's really down to the experience you intend to give to your user.

It really comes down to the design process, choosing these design patterns can be a very lengthy and involved process. Designers can agonise over this process extensively.

I could keep listing design suggestions but really google is your friend on this one, research and get inspired. Alternatively isolate your element in a [codepen](http://codepen.io) and play around with it. It can be really fun experimenting with different styles and animation combinations.